# java String compare did not match

Tags: java, string-comparison

below is my coding:

```
package functiontest;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FunctionTest {
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int option=0;
    System.out.println("Please enter your position:");
    System.out.println("\n\t1.\tAdministrator");
    System.out.println("\t2.\tManagement");
    System.out.println("\t3.\tClerk");
    System.out.println("\t4.\tEngineer");
    System.out.println("\t5.\tExit system");
    System.out.print("\n\tYour position:\t");
    do
    {
        option = scan.nextInt();
        if(option<1 || option > 5) System.out.print("You have enter wrong position" + 
"\nPlease choose your position again[1...5]:\t");
    }while(option<1 || option > 5);

    switch(option)
    {
        case 1:administrator();break;
        case 2:System.exit(0);break;
    }


}
public static void administrator()
{
    Scanner ascan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String username="administrator";
    String password="password";
    String iusername, ipassword;

    do{
        System.out.print("Please enter username:\t");
        iusername = ascan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Your username:\t" + iusername);
        System.out.print("Please enter password:\t");
        ipassword = ascan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("The password you enter:\t" + ipassword);
        if(iusername.equalsIgnoreCase(username) && ipassword.equalsIgnoreCase(password))
        {
            System.out.println("you have enter wrong username or password");
            System.out.println("The system will exit");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }while(iusername.equalsIgnoreCase(username) && ipassword.equalsIgnoreCase(password));

        int option;
        System.out.println("Login successful!");
        System.out.println("1. \tadd clerk");
        System.out.println("2. \tdelete clerk");
        System.out.println("3. \tadd engineer");
        System.out.println("4. \tdelete engineer");
        option = ascan.nextInt();ascan.nextLine();
}
```

}

firstly i assign my username and password:

```
    String username="administrator";
    String password="password";
```

read the username and password from user key in

```
iusername = ascan.nextLine();
ipassword = ascan.nextLine();
```

last doing compare between password and username:

```
iusername.equalsIgnoreCase(username) && ipassword.equalsIgnoreCase(password)
```

here is the result after i run the program:

```
run:
Please enter your position:

1.  Administrator
2.  Management
3.  Clerk
4.  Engineer
5.  Exit system

Your position:  1
Please enter username:  administrator
Your username:  administrator
Please enter password:  password
The password you enter: password
you have enter wrong username or password
The system will exit
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 22 seconds)
```

when i do compare username and password, it always said unmatch, after i try to print the username and password i key in, i was very sure i am correct, 
but the program always said i have key in wrong username and password, may i know where i did wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Look at your code.  You've said "if the user name and password are correct, print a message saying they're wrong, and exit."

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
if(iusername.equalsIgnoreCase(username) && ipassword.equalsIgnoreCase(password))
```

you want

```
if(!iusername.equalsIgnoreCase(username) || !ipassword.equalsIgnoreCase(password))
```

Your goal is to print the error message if either the username or password are incorrect, not if both are correct.

Answer (score 1):

You exit the loop in the first iteration. The comparison works fine, but you're telling the program to print the error message even though it is right.

```
 if(iusername.equalsIgnoreCase(username) && ipassword.equalsIgnoreCase(password))
    {
        System.out.println("you have enter wrong username or password");
        System.out.println("The system will exit");
        System.exit(0);
    }
```

You probably want

```
 if(!iusername.equalsIgnoreCase(username) || !ipassword.equalsIgnoreCase(password))
```

Add the `!`s

**Edit:**

Your use of the loop is POINTLESS. If you don't intend to loop, then just take out the loop portion. If the system exits upon a bad input, what's the purpose of looping?

Al you need is this, if you don't want it to loop upon valid input and exit upon invalid input

```
    System.out.print("Please enter username:\t");
    iusername = ascan.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Your username:\t" + iusername);
    System.out.print("Please enter password:\t");
    ipassword = ascan.nextLine();
    System.out.println("The password you enter:\t" + ipassword);
    if(!iusername.equalsIgnoreCase(username) || !ipassword.equalsIgnoreCase(password))
    {
        System.out.println("you have enter wrong username or password");
        System.out.println("The system will exit");
        System.exit(0);
    }
```

Forget the loop!

Comment: it did not change anything but continue at the 
do-while loop with condition 
    iusername.equalsIgnoreCase(username) && ipassword.equalsIgnoreCase(password)

Comment: What exactly do you expect it do?

Comment: the username and password should match as 
iusername=administrator
ipassword=password, as i initial them

Comment: Your use of the loop is POINTLESS. If you don't intend to loop, then just take out the loop portion. If the system exit upon bad input, what's the purpose of looping. See my edit.